# When viewing a report inside an application, the parameter prompt redisplays when moving to the next page

Tags: crystal-reports, paging

I'm pretty much a novice with crystal reports.  We have another team making our reports, and I'm integrating it with the application.  The problem is with paging and user defined parameters.  Essentially, the document.table. setdatasource points at our query result set (set in code).  The report, upon opening, will then prompt the user for the parameter, which will further reduce the displayed result to the user as the prompt parameter is part of the record selection formula.

```
AND
{@Age} >= 20 and
{@Age} < 30 and
{Report;1.Sector} = {?NewSector})
```

This will return a table of more than one page in length.  However, requesting the next page will result in the user being prompted for the Sector again, and once provided, will take the user back to page 1 of the results again.

If I take out the reference to the parameter, then obviously the paging works fine.

Is there away to just take the parameter once from the user, and then reuse this value in the subsequent paging requests?

Appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.  I had the report refreshing every postback.

*EDit*

A bit more elaboration:

I have the report being created in a RefreshReports procedure, which sets up the report as follows:

```
 Dim objConnectionInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(ApplicationConstants.MyDB).ConnectionString)
    Dim myConnBuilder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myconnection.ConnectionString)

    '// Log on credentials from web.config
    objConnectionInfo = New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
    objConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False
    objConnectionInfo.ServerName = myconnection.DataSource
    objConnectionInfo.UserID = myConnBuilder.UserID
    objConnectionInfo.Password = myConnBuilder.Password

    crConnectionInfo = objConnectionInfo


    '// Get the report details needed
    rep = Request.QueryString("Report")
    crDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(rep))
    crDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(myConnBuilder.UserID, myConnBuilder.Password)

    Dim crDatabase As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database

    Dim crTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables
    Dim aTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table

    crDatabase = crDoc.Database
    crTables = crDatabase.Tables
```

There is then a series of else ifs like the following:

```
ElseIf rep = "ExampleRep.rpt" Then
        For Each aTable In crTables
            If aTable.Name = "GetSectorRep;1" Then
                Dim NewSector As String = ""
                    NewSector = Session("NewSector").ToString()
                aTable.SetDataSource(DAL.GetSectorRepTable(NewSector))
            End If
        Next
```

In my Page_Init I grab the query strings I need and call RefreshReports.  The problem I was having was that I was also requesting RefreshReports in a  If Postback on page_load, which meant that every time the report posted back (eg. new page) it was requesting the parameter again, as the report was being created afresh.

So, silly me -  quite an obvious mistake in the end!