# Crystal report pagination isnt working for date parameters but is with others

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report written in CR for VS2010. The report will produce invoices over a range of either invoice numbers or dates. To that end, the report has 4 parameters (fromInvoice, toInvoice, fromDate & toDate). The stored procedure can handle nulls for any of the fields so it can receive

If I run the report with just invoice numbers the reports pagination works fine, same for invoice numbers and dates combined (and the parameters persist across the pagination). But if I search with just the from and to dates then it returns the correct number of pages (as visible in the web viewer) but when I click next then it seems to lose the date parameters and displays all the invoices produced, ever.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? why would a date parameter not persist when other parameters have?
the report is called from the same underlying c# page.

Comment: Related to this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321414/when-viewing-a-report-inside-an-application-the-parameter-prompt-redisplays-when

Comment: not sure if its related... I've asked the OP in the post you linked to supply a bit more info so I can try it out. thanks

Comment: fixed. viewer needed viewstatemode='enabled' adding to the aspx page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed. viewer needed viewstatemode='enabled' adding to the aspx page